# undefined method 'inline' for ImageScience:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, image-science

I am migrating a Rails 2.1.2 application to Rails 2.3.11

To make my life easier i used bundler but I get the following error when starting my server:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/image_science-1.2.1/lib/image_science.rb:90: undefined method `inline' for ImageScience:Class (NoMethodError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `require'
        from ./script/../config/boot.rb:113:in `load_gems'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
        from /Users/michaelkoper/code/beruby_git/config/environment.rb:18
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/commands/server.rb:84
        from script/server:3:in `require'
        from script/server:3
```

It is kind of strange because i got it working without bundler. I think i am missing a gem dependency.

Gemfile:

```
    gem 'mperham-deadlock_retry', :require => 'deadlock_retry'
    gem 'hoptoad_notifier', '2.4.2'
    gem 'will_paginate', '~> 2.3.15'
    gem "activemerchant", :require => "active_merchant"
    gem "newrelic_rpm"
    gem 'calendar_date_select'
    gem 'ckeditor', '3.4.3'     gem 'automatic_foreign_key'
    gem 'chronic'
    gem 'mechanize'
    gem 'rexml-expansion-fix'
    gem 'image_science', '1.2.1'
    gem 'inline', '0.1.0'
```

bundle install:

```
    Using rake (0.8.7) 
    Using activesupport (2.3.11) 
    Using rack (1.1.2) 
    Using actionpack (2.3.11) 
    Using actionmailer (2.3.11) 
    Using builder (3.0.0) 
    Using braintree (2.10.0) 
    Using activemerchant (1.14.0) 
    Using activerecord (2.3.11) 
    Using activeresource (2.3.11) 
    Using redhillonrails_core (1.1.3) 
    Using automatic_foreign_key (1.2.0) 
    Using calendar_date_select (1.16.2) 
    Using cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0) 
    Using hoe (2.8.0) 
    Using chronic (0.2.3) 
    Using mime-types (1.16) 
    Using ckeditor (3.4.3) 
    Using columnize (0.3.2) 
    Using daemons (1.0.10) 
    Using fastthread (1.0.7) 
    Using gem_plugin (0.2.3) 
    Using highline (1.6.1) 
    Using hoptoad_notifier (2.4.2) 
    Using image_science (1.2.1) 
    Using inline (0.1.0) 
    Using linecache (0.43) 
    Using nokogiri (1.4.4) 
    Using mechanize (0.9.3) 
    Using mongrel (1.1.5) 
    Using mperham-deadlock_retry (1.0.0) 
    Using mysql (2.8.1) 
    Using newrelic_rpm (2.14.1) 
    Using rails (2.3.11) 
    Using rexml-expansion-fix (1.0.1) 
    Using ruby-debug-base (0.10.4) 
    Using ruby-debug (0.10.4) 
    Using will_paginate (2.3.15) 
    Using bundler (1.0.7)
```

Comment: is ImageScience one of your own models or is it a dependency of another library/gem etc?

Comment: @Tyran East, ImageScience isnt a model i created

Comment: Ok i 'solved' it. I deleted inline from the gem spec and changed image science to version 1.1.3. It is not the solution so i keep this question alive. I really want to use the newest version....

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like you probably want this answer: [ImageScience breaks on update to Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280878/imagescience-breaks-on-update-to-rails-3/4473192#4473192)

Comment: image_science has RubyInline and hoe(1.2.1) as dependencies indeed. But i dont think that hack will fix it tho... And i dont want to require image_science everywhere because i use it a lot... I will give it a try anyways

Comment: Is it possible that you just need to put the "inline" line before the "image_science" line in the Gemfile? I don't actually know if the Gemfile ordering matters... but it might be worth a shot.